# Stream Builder is not changing the screen even after changing the Auth State because of using PageView

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a stream builder which is changing the screen based on the Auth state (if the user logged in or signed up it should change the screen to (HomeScreen)) the problem is when I signup the screen will change and it will go to the (HomeScreen) but when I login the screen will not change until I press the restart button, the problem is with the (PageView) because when I put the LoginScreen before the SignupScreen in the PageView children then after the login the screen will change but after the signup the screen will not change, here is my code:

```
 home: StreamBuilder(
    stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
    builder: (ctx, AsyncSnapshot userSnapshot) {
      print(userSnapshot.data);
      if (userSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
        return const Center(
          child: Text("Loading..."),
        );
      }
      if (userSnapshot.hasData) {
        return const HomeScreen();
      }
      return Stack(
        children: [
          PageView(
            controller: _pageController,
            children: [
              SignupScreen(),
              const LoginScreen(),
            ],
          ),
```

Comment: Do not do this: `stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),` or you'll forever be in the loading state

Comment: But I'm using this for getting the state of user whether it logged in or not.

Comment: Did you ever find out a solution for this issue? Im also facing the same problem when using page view for have the user create account and then login them in. the authstatechage is working properly. the page view is just not letting the app redirect the user